# What limitation is intended by Seeming's "basic arrangement of limbs"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

The description of the spell [Seeming](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Seeming#content) contains the following text (emphasis mine)

> You can make each creature seem 1 foot shorter or taller and appear thin, fat, or in between. You can’t change a target’s body type, so **you must choose a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs**. Otherwise, the extent of the illusion is up to you.

The way I see it, there are three potential interpretations of the bolded text. Either:

1. The limbs of the pre-/post-illusion creature must be similar (arms are arms, legs are legs, etc.)
2. The limbs must be positioned in a similar manner
3. Both of the above limitations must be met

With that in mind, **what limitation is intended by "basic arrangement of limbs"?** Would a wolf be a suitable choice, for example, or would the fact that it's a quadruped disallow it as an option? Are there any FAQs, Sage Advice, designer tweets, or examples in other material that indicate how different a Seeming's form can really be?

Answer (score 13):

## Generally, the number and position of limbs should match. Beyond that it's up to the DM.

*Disguise Self* has similar wording:

> You can seem 1 foot shorter or taller and can appear thin, fat, or in between. You can’t change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs. Otherwise, the extent of the illusion is up to you.

But there are no strict rules about what "body type" means.

We can assume that shapes with a different number of limbs -- a centaur or a xorn or a marilith demon -- are definitely not possible. And presumably (assuming humanoid targets) both *seeming* and *disguise self* can produce the forms of other humanoids.

But there are a few other cases that might obtain, and it's up to the DM to rule in these cases:

**Quadrupeds.** Animals like wolves (as mentioned in the question) have limbs with the same number of joints at the same general positions on the torso. So an argument could be made that they have the same "basic arrangement of limbs" as a humanoid. Contrariwise, an argument could be made that arms are not the same as legs, or that plantigrade legs (like humans and bears have) aren't the same as digitigrade legs (like a canine or feline has). This is really a DM call; the intent of *disguise self* seems to be that such forms are not ones the spell can produce; with *seeming* it's not so clear.

**Tails.** Are tails limbs? Can a tiefling hide their tail with *disguise self* or *seeming*? Can a humanoid without a tail use *seeming* to appear like a lizardfolk, with a substantial tail? Here we have a Sage Advice rulings:

> A tiefling's tail isn't considered a limb; it's not prehensile.

([source](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/03/08/is-a-tieflings-tail-a-limb/))

From this we can assume that limbs that don't have any game effect aren't considered for this purpose.

If I were DM in this case, I would rule that *seeming* (and *disguse self*) can't cause humans to appear as quadrupeds, and that those spells can't hide (or produce) a tail that functions as more than a cosmetic detail.

Answer (score -3):

The main point of that restriction is to not permit limbs to be added, such as wings, or extra arms, etc.

I tend to be fairly permissive for creative characters, so I would allow the spell to "create" or hide a tail.  I would allow the caster to look like a quadruped, although I would require a deception roll to fool others, if he was going to try to move more than a tiny amount in that form.